# Adding search engine optimization to site.com site

Tags: site.com

For those using Site.com for the CMS, how do you do SEO? Is it even possible?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any specific SEO information you are looking for or just in a general sense?

Comment: Just in a general sense. I'm new to it, but our website manager has asked how we can incorporate it to our Site.com site.

Comment: Is there something about site.com that prevents normal SEO tips from applying?

Answer (score 3):

You can add any metadata to page Headers such as page title and description, you can also import configuration files like Sitemap.XML, .HTaccess, and Robots.txt into the CMS by dragging them onto the browser.
Hope this helps. 
Source: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/CRC:Siteforce

Comment: Site.com does not support .htacess files.